# How to add a WCF Service to a VS 2017 cross plattform shared project

Tags: wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm new in Xamarin and I would like to consume a WCF Service, and I don't find any solution to add a WCF Service to the shared project.

I've a shared project, so in that case I don't have references in my shared project, and can't choose "connected service" or "service reference" to add a service.

I couldn't find any good solution! Is this possible, and when yes, what is the right way to add a wcf service to a shared project.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Have you checked the official guide https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/ ?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, I have to implement the service in every plattform.

Comment: Here is another official guide with example: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/wcf/

Comment: I found using web Api is much easier instead of Wcf if your requirement is not very extended.